pnpm production build for pnpm monorepo app having local workspace package dependency
I have pnpm mono-repo and it works perfectly for local build and development server using build for app. For development, I am using
pnpm --filter=@ap/auth-service --prod deploy @prod/auth-service
pnpm --filter=@ap/order-service --prod deploy @prod/order-service
folder structure
root
├── package.json                   // Root level dependency
├── pnpm-workspace.yaml            // pnpm workspace configuration
├── packages                       // Packages folder containing shared, server, and services
│   ├── shared                     // Shared resources, if any
│   ├── server                     // Server related resources, if any
│   └── services                   // Common services folder
└── apps                           // Separate apps folder
    ├── auth-service
    │   ├── package.json           // Service specific dependency -> @ap/auth-service
    │   ├── tsconfig               // TypeScript configuration for auth-service
    │   └── src                    // Source code for auth-service
    └── order-service
        ├── package.json           // Service specific dependency -> @ap/order-service
        ├── tsconfig               // TypeScript configuration for order-service
        └── src                    // Source code for order-service

pnpm workspace.yaml
packages:
  - 'packages/*'
  - 'apps/*'

The build folder dist file is taking the reference from the actual working package directory instead of installed package in node modules, how can I use production ready build for pnpm mono-repo which has local workspace dependency
I tried pnpm deploy command which I assume is taking the local tsconfig for build
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "lib": ["ES2021", "dom"],
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@user-module/*": ["src/module/user/*"],
      "@anc-module/*": ["src/module/organization/*"],
      "@product-module/*": ["src/module/auth/*"],
      "@config/*": ["src/config/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["src/shared/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["."],
  "exclude": ["build", "node_modules", "coverage"]
}

How this pnpm deploy comand is taking build command of the package.json of the app/auth0service and using its tsconfig,
if I use build command directly using this
auth-service/package.json
script : {
  build: `rimraf ./build && npx tsc`
}

This also produce same result for its build using this command
pnpm --filter=@sn/auth-service --prod deploy @prod/auth-service

After pnpm deploy,  I run the pnpm install command inside the deployed folder @prod/auth-service, which I assume should install all the dependency for the auth service in node_module, which I can see is in the node_module as

@ap/shared
@ap/service
@ap/server

I am not able to use the build folder independently with node modules as the imports are still referring to the original package code instead of node-modules which should be installed from the
package.json
{

  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development&&nodemon",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production&& node build/src/index.js",
    "build": "rimraf ./build && npx tsc",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=development jest"
  },
  
  "dependencies": {
    "@sinclair/typebox": "^0.31.17",
    "@ap/server": "workspace:^",
    "@ap/service": "workspace:^",
    "@ap/shared": "workspace:^",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
   
  },
 
}


I am stuck on the exact same issue at the moment. Did you ever find a solution to this?

This depends upon your workspace setting and build setup, by default root is in the onom workspace. Anything that is within the workspace will install dependencies using symlink. The pnpm deploy command will make sure all the dependencies are installed in the withing your deployed unit, you can just use the new deploy build directly untouched with your start command. Even if it has local workspace but you can't run any npm install or pnpm install further.
Make sure the path is not in your workspace can use @deploy/{your_mono_repo_app}

Other way is using containerised image as suggested by the pnpm to build the applciaiton as base image and then move the deployed folder to the new image
Once this was sorted I was having issue with prisma generation, which adds the new client after pnpm install, so I added it as post install dependency as suggested by prisma doc and then it worked fine.
I am using both local deployed build and docker containerised image
Accordingly you can setup your build steps if you push all your app first and then deploy
Ref: https://pnpm.io/docker

Third way is you publish your packages to registry or private git and then use lib versioning so it will become independent and you can use your apps as independent deployed unit,
